# Windows 8: CreateFile() returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, immediate GetLastError shows 0

Tags: c++, c, createfile

I am opening a file with `CreateFile` on Windows 8 from within a printer filter environment. The code is effectively straight C, even though the filter is built in C++. `CreateFile` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` but an immediate call to `GetLastError` returns 0. I have seen this before, back in the old NT4 days (and through to Windows 7) if a directory of the same name as the file existed, a file open attempt would fail with error 0; but I have checked and the file name is different from any subdirectories in the destination directory.

Code:

```
io_buf[fh].fh = CreateFile(name, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, p_sa,
                           CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, (HANDLE)0);
io_buf[fh].read_mode = FALSE;
io_buf[fh].file_start = 0L;
io_buf[fh].folder = 0;

if (io_buf[fh].fh == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    LogMsg("BufCreate: CreateFile failed (%ld); retrying with SharedWrite\r\n", GetLastError());
    io_buf[fh].fh = CreateFile(name, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, p_sa,
                               CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, (HANDLE) 0);
}
if (io_buf[fh].fh == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    LogMsg("BufCreate: CreateFile failed (%ld)\r\n", GetLastError());
    return (Vers_FAILURE);
}
```

LogMsg output:

> Render 15:41:46.715: BufCreate: CreateFile failed (0); retrying with SharedWrite
>
> Render 15:41:46.715: BufCreate: CreateFile failed (0)

Because this occurs relatively randomly, sending it to MS would not work; they'd fire it back to me with a "no rep" and I'd get dinged for the SRX. Has anyone got any clue on how I would proceed?

Comment: Try disabling the AV and see if it still happens.

Comment: GetLastError()() returns a DWORD.  Not sure if '%ld' is the correct specifier?

Comment: Whatever it is, it seems to happen every 10 years http://forum.sysinternals.com/createfile-fails-but-getlasterror0_topic3098.html ;-) P.S. Is LogMsg an actual function, or a macro, or something else?

Comment: What dxiv said. Without seeing what `LogMsg` is, we cannot tell if the call to `GetLastError` is or isn't "immediate". It could be `#define LogMsg(x, y) if (someFunc()) printf(x, y)` for all we know.

Comment: You might want to start by looking at the environment: 1) is there room on the disk 2) is the number directories exceeding the max allowed at that level 3) does the program have permission to create a file 4) try using the C library rather than the MSDN functions  5) does the parent directory have the appropriate permissions for the program to create files  6) does the `access list` not have the user or group of the program listed 7) Are you running on a `quota` system and the program is trying to exceed that quota

Comment: The posted code has a serious shortcoming for debugging, as it does not expose the exact path/name of the file to be created.   Strongly suggest moving the check for the error to before modifying the parameters of the file descriptor

Comment: @user3629249 The C library calls the MSDN functions in the end. Hard to see the point of that recommendation.

Comment: Perhaps I'm out-of-date, but the last time I looked, the C functions called the `libc` library, not the MSDN library.

Comment: @user3629249 More of a nitpick on terminology, but what you call `MSDN functions` is commonly referred to as the [Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516.aspx) (which used to be called `Win32 API`). The C library functions are indeed implemented in some `libc` library, but if you follow the CRT source code they all end up calling the API at some point, and that's inevitable since the i/o is always platform specific at the lowest level.

Comment: Yeah ^^^ what @DavidSchwartz says.  I don't know why I did not spot that.  Call GLE IMMEDIATELY and store it's return value.

Comment: Sorry about the delay in answering; I thought I'd get immediate mail when someone answered. kichik: AV on Win8 is MSE, no way to turn it off. MartinJames, %ld (longint = 32 bits = DWORD) works, it will give a negative value for 0x8nnnnnnn but Windows Calculator wil hexify it no problem. dxiv, DavidSchwartz, LogMsg is a straight function call, the result of GLE is pushed straight onto the stack. user6629249 the file name is logged elsewhere.

Comment: user6629249 continued: Environment: 1) 500GB free. 2) it's writing to c:\temp\_000.tif and \temp\ has about 40 subdirectories. 3) see edited question above 4) C library eventually calls the Windows API, don't see how that would help, as EJP says 5) yes 6) ACL for c:\temp includes inherited authenticated users read/write/create 7) no quota

Answer (score 1):

This is vexing. Turns out that I was not writing the file where I thought I was, and that's why it failed. But it should have returned error 5 (Access denied), and I was led up a stump because of this bedamned 0 in GetLastError.

For what it's worth: I had created a path to a temp directory. Because my security context at the time was LocalSystem (I'm in the PrinterPipeline service), that file was in c:\Windows\System32\Services\LocalService\AppData\Local\Temp. No ordinary user can reach that space, and the attempt will quite possibly leave your OS hooped. I had changed to user security context to write to C:\Temp, and was getting a failure because I had forgotten to change my filename to C:\Temp. The error 0 made it look like possibly I was faced with file system redirection mapping c:\temp into LocalService space.

Correcting that so that I was actually writing where I thought I was got rid of the failure... but I still don't understand why Windows was handing me back an error 0.